# Azure Mobile Service Api custom call returning empty byte array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a mobile service custom controller returning some rows from db as xml. Calling the localhost:xxx/api/getsomrows returns data, so that part is ok.

```
[self.client invokeAPI:@"getsomerows" body:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" parameters:@{@"Id":item} 

// sent as query-string parameters headers:nil completion:^(NSData *result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Result: %d", [result count]); }];
```

Returning a single int or string value works using "id result" as return type, but when im returning two or more objects I get a byte array with the right number of rows but without any data totally empty. Ive tried result type as `NSData* , NSObject, NSString`  but all turn out empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: (id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) used this completion block.
check what is the output on server side using log.

Comment: Thanks for the respons. Found the solution. I called the api with a MSAPIBlock, when i should have used a MSAPIDataBlock. Microsoft or apple should really provided some example code or better documentation for this .

Comment: This is the right way to call mobile service/web api when requestion multiple value return :  <br/>  <!-- language: c -->- (void) getAll:(MSAPIDataBlock)completion
{
    [self.client
     invokeAPI:@"getalltest"
     data:nil
     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
     parameters:nil
     headers:nil
     completion:completion ];
}